# Issue inserting data into a database

Tags: php, mysql

I run this function and the value of the post form doesn't insert into the DB. I'm not getting any error messages but I checked and saw that $this->user_id is populating. Am I missing something else?

```
function senddata () {
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","XXXXX");
    if (!$con)
        {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }
        mysql_select_db("user", $con);
        $sql="INSERT INTO profile (collegemajor) VALUE('$_POST[major]') WHERE userid=$this->user_id";

    mysql_close($con);

    }
```

Comment: are you executing the query? by using mysql_query function?

Comment: also remove where clause from insert statement

Comment: But I need to insert the value into a certain row, where the user id is the equivalent of the active user. How can I do that?

Comment: then you use update statement. for example "update profile set collegemajor = '$_POST[major]' WHERE userid = $this->user_id"

Comment: How would I update more than one field?

Comment: just separate columns by comma. for example you have another column collegeyear then use this statment. "update profile set collegemajor = '$_POST[major]', collegeyear = 2011 WHERE userid = $this->user_id"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I don't see the mysql_query() - the function to execute the query.

It seems like the problem is here:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO profile (collegemajor) VALUE('$_POST[major]') WHERE userid=$this->user_id";
```

Use `$sql="INSERT INTO profile (collegemajor) VALUE('$_POST[major]');` instead.

The code:

```
    function senddata () {
        $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","XXXXX");
        if (!$con)
            {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
            }
            mysql_select_db("user", $con);
            $sql="INSERT INTO profile (collegemajor) VALUE('$_POST[major]');";
        mysql_query( $sql , $con );

        mysql_close($con);

        }
```

Comment: I need to insert the value into the row of the active user, hence the where query, is this not possible?

Comment: @MattMcClintock So you need `$sql = "UPDATE your_table SET collemajor = " . $_POST['major'] . " WHERE userid = " . $this -> user_id .";";`

Comment: function sendschool () {
        $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","xxxxx");
        if (!$con)
            {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
            }
            mysql_select_db("user", $con);
            $sql = "UPDATE profile SET school='$_POST[school]' WHERE userid=$this->user_id";
            mysql_query( $sql , $con );

            mysql_close($con);

        } ##All good now

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5929/discussion-between-michael-sazonov-and-matt-mcclintock)

Answer (score 1):

1. INSERT statement don't have WHERE clausule,
2. you need to send query!!!

Comment: Wow ) I'd totally missed that it's an "INSERT" query )

Answer (score 0):

This should be an update function, it seems, rather than an insert function (if you're trying to update a row that already exists, which is seems you are based on the "Where" clause).

And, as others have mentioned, you never ran mysql_query() or similar function.